# problems in spring batch mongo itemreader?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-batch

I found a weird issue with MongoItemReader.
This is the configuration I've for a step:

```
    private Step addMnpInformation() throws Exception {
    return stepBuilders.get("addMnpInformation")
            .chunk(50)
            .reader(stagedCdrReader())
            .processor(addMnpProcessor())
            .writer(stagedCdrWriter())
            .build();
}
```

and this is the reader

```
@Bean
public MongoItemReader<StagedCdr> stagedCdrReader() throws Exception {
    MongoItemReader reader = new MongoItemReader<StagedCdr>();
    reader.setTemplate(stagingCdrTransactionManager);
    reader.setQuery("{cdrStatus:'PENDING'}");
    reader.setTargetType(StagedCdr.class);
    HashMap<String,Direction> sort = new HashMap<String, Direction>();
    sort.put("sequence", Direction.ASC);
    reader.setSort(sort);
    reader.setName("stagedCdrReader");
    reader.afterPropertiesSet();

    return reader;
}
```

It seems the reader is not reading every other page. The records I'm procesing has a sequential Id and I found it's reading records using a page of 50 (probably my chunk size) but in this way:

from 0 to 49
from 100 to 149
from 200 to 249
.
.
.

to it's not reading
from 50 to 99
from 150 to 199

how many items be skiped is depend on chunk property, for example chunk(50),then 50 items would be skiped, I don't know why!

Answer (score 0):

Robin? Is that you?

I posted the same question to Spring Forums some time ago and forgot about it.
This is why it's happening:

I discovered that the processor was changing the field cdrStatus to COMPLETED. That way, when the reader requested the new page and it's using limit and skip, the changed records of the first page where not included in the new page request so the 'new' first page was skipped and records not retrieved.

What I don't know if it's the expected behavior. You can find the thread here: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/129604-problems-with-mongoitemreader